# How can I install docker on Debian 8 kernel 2.6.32

Tags: docker, debian

I've bought a Debian 8 VPS for 3e per month https://www.pulseheberg.com/vps/simple.

I would like to install docker engine but it not works ( cause it need a kernel >= 3.10)

Do you have any idea for install docker on my server ?

Answer (score 1):

[Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216191/docker-minimum-kernel-version-3-8-13-or-3-10)

You can't. Sorry to bear the bad news.

Docker backport-supports kernel **3.10** but not below. Here is a [copy/paste from their doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/):

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Debian version. Additionally, your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum. The latest 3.10 minor version or a newer maintained version are also acceptable.
>
> Kernels older than 3.10 lack some of the features required to run Docker containers. These older versions are known to have bugs which cause data loss and frequently panic under certain conditions.