# Why does docker not run with kernels older than 3.10?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers

Docker doesn't run on Linux kernels older than 3.10 in general. (In some cases, it can be run in 3.8 kernel too).

What are the features in new kernels missing in the older ones that prevent docker from running in them?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216191/docker-minimum-kernel-version-3-8-13-or-3-10)

Comment: From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#prerequisites): "Kernels older than 3.10 lack some of the features required to run Docker containers. These older versions are known to have bugs which cause data loss and frequently panic under certain conditions".

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7528#issuecomment-97610585) discussion.

Answer (score 3):

> A 3.10 Linux kernel is the minimum requirement for Docker. Kernels
>   older than 3.10 lack some of the features required to run Docker
>   containers. These older versions are known to have bugs which cause
>   data loss and frequently panic under certain conditions.
>
> The latest minor version (3.x.y) of the 3.10 (or a newer maintained
>   version) Linux kernel is recommended. Keeping the kernel up to date
>   with the latest minor version will ensure critical kernel bugs get
>   fixed.

Taken from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries